# Words clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-computing

I'm trying to cluster some words (let's take car brands). In order to do that I can't use k-means or k-medoids so I've tried to use [Affinity Propagation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html) from Sklearn. And I'm using it with `levenshtein` from the distance lib or `damerau_levenshtein_distance` from the `pyxdameraulevenshtein` lib.

Example here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

However, these metrics are not exactly the ones I need. For example, MERCEDES-BENZ and MERCEDES have a 5 distance, the same as VOLVO and FIAT. Do you guys know some metrics which would give a higher similarity score between MERCEDES-BENZ and MERCEDES than VOLVO and FIAT.

Thanks,
Djokx

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jaccard similarity from the tri-grams composing those words. That is, you decompose each word in their three-character components (for volvo: vol, olv, lvo) and get their Jaccard similarity to each other set. [N-gram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram).

Jaccard similarity is defined as the ratio between **number of common n-grams** and **number of total n-grams**: [Jaccard index](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).